# Android MergeCursor broken on version > 3.x?

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

Has anyone used this class and see if it is broken in android version 3.x and above? It worked fine for me in previous versions. Here's an example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
MatrixCursor cursorOne = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{ "_id", "name", "description" }); 

cursorOne.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 2", "Description 2" }); 
cursorOne.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 3", "Description 3" }); 
cursorOne.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 4", "Description 4" }); 
cursorOne.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 5", "Description 5" }); 

CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursorOne, new String[] { "name", "description" }, new int []{ android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }); 

MatrixCursor cursorTwo = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{ "_id", "name", "description" }); 

cursorTwo.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 2", "Description 2" }); 
cursorTwo.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 3", "Description 3" }); 
cursorTwo.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 4", "Description 4" }); 
cursorTwo.addRow(new Object[]{ 5, "Object 5", "Description 5" }); 

MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] { cursorOne, cursorTwo }); 

cursorAdapter.changeCursor(mergeCursor);

setListAdapter(cursorAdapter); 
}
```

It doesn't show anything, it seems like it's cleaning the cursors. Am I missing something for the `SDK` > 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution:

I replaced the `CursorAdapter` and `SimpleCursorAdapter` imports for the ones on the compatibility package and used `CursorAdapter.swapCursor` instead of `CursorAdapter.changeCursor`.

Seems to be something related that `swapCursor` does not close the previous cursor.